# Tabs Semantic Ui React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

[image: Screen Capture]
Hi Everyones. I just have a question about the react library Semantic Ui React, I am trying to use the tab module with pointing, all it's works fine but I want to change the color of the cursor at the bottom of each tab like you can see at the picture. I already set up all my project for theming I just don't know which global variable I need to add or override ... 
If someone can help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the css class from Semanti-ui-react to get the desired result.
Add this in the css file and change the color to desired one,

```
.active.item {
   border-color: blue !important;
}
```

Here is the working example, [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2fdso)

[image]

Note: Please try to post the code instead if images from next time.